# Angular4 Template

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have written a simple code to demonstrate ngTemplate

```
   <div> <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet] ="template1"> </ng-container></div>
```

and here are the template

```
 <ng-template #template1> This is 1st template </ng-template>
 <ng-template #template2>This is 2nd template </ng-template>
```

It is working as expected, but my problem is I am not able to pass dynamic value to `[ngTemplateOutlet]`

I want to achieve something like this

```
<div> <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet] ="selectTemplate"></ng-container> </div>
```

Which will either select `template1` or `template2`.

Whenever I am passing some dynamic value which I have defined in my typescript file it gives is error

`ERROR TypeError: templateRef.createEmbeddedView is not a function`

My typescript file contains this code

```
if(some condition) {
     this.selectTemplate = "template1";
} else {
     this.selectTemplate = "template2";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first example, you're binding `ngTemplateOutlet` to the value of the expression `template1`, which is the first `ngTemplate` element. So far so good.

In your second example, you're binding `ngTemplateOutlet` to the value of the expression `selectTemplate`, which is *not* a template element - you've set it to be a string!

To fix this, you first need to add the template references to your component as fields using the `ViewChild` annotation:

```
@ViewChild('template1') template1;
@ViewChild('template2') template2;
```

Then set `selectTemplate` to refer to the element itself rather than its name:

```
if (some condition) {
     this.selectTemplate = this.template1;
}
else {
     this.selectTemplate = this.template2;
}
```

Note that the `ViewChild` variables will not be set until the component's view has been initialized - you can use the `ngViewAfterInit`hook to wait for that to happen.

Comment: Instead of `ngViewAfterInit` i have to use `ngOnInit` to achieve the desired behaviour. thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

**update Angular 5**

`ngOutletContext` was renamed to `ngTemplateOutletContext`

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#500-beta5-2017-08-29

**original**

You can pass a context

```
<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="template1; context: {foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar', $implicit: 'implit' }"
```

In the template you can use it like

```
<ng-template #template1 let-foo1="foo" let-foo2="bar" let-item>
  This is 1st template
  <div>foo1: {{foo1}}</div> 
  <div>foo2: {{foo2}}</div>      
  <div>foo1: {{item}}</div>    
 </ng-template>
```

I hope the names I used are not too confusing. I tried to make the distinction between

- the name as the value is passed to the context
- the name as it is used inside the template
- $implicit which doesn't require `="somename"` in the template variable definintion (`let-item`)